# Microphone on ipad 1 vs ipad 2 (developed with flex)

Tags: apache-flex, ipad, microphone

I have a simple application that plays microphone -  the code is taken from :

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/android/9781449308001/exploring-the-apis/microphone#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODE0NDkzMDgwMDEvNDY=

This sample works fine on Ipad 2 but not on Ipad 1 (inconsistent behavior, sometimes plays a few seconds and breaks).

was anyone able to use the microphone on Ipad 1 (developed with flex 4.5.1), I need a very simple thing - record voice and play it

Thanks

Comment: +1 for good question, please post some code though (even if it is based off that code, could be something ancillary you've added - or can you verify even that code has the flaw?).

Comment: To be clear, what part is the problem: recording from the microphone, or playing the result back through the speakers?

Comment: Playing the results is where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing your buffer size for playback. This is located in the playSound function and in the example it is set to 8192 which should be more than enough. Try 16384 and see if that fixes it. Please note that this may make your playback seem to be delayed.

Are you compiling this application in Debug or Release mode to test? Sound playback is usually choppy in Debug mode and performs significantly better in Release.